# How to create an AWS Lambda/API gateway python function that takes a pdf file as input using multipart/form-data?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I have been struggling with this for a while now. I need to create a resource in API gateway linking to a lambda function that takes a pdf file as input sent as a multipart/form-data POST request. To make it simple, I am just returning the file for now.

When I try to call the API with the following curl, I get *Internal server error* from AWS. Did anyone ever succeeded to send a pdf file to Lambda without having to use the S3 trick (upload to S3)?

Thank you all in advance for any hint.

**Commands/Files:**

*curl*

```
curl -vvv -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "content=@file.pdf" https://...MYAPIHERE.../pdf
```

I am currently using serverless and python3.

Below are my files:

*Servelerlss.yaml*

```
function:
  pdf:
    handler: handler.pdf
    events:
      - http:
          path: /pdf
          method: post 
          integration: lambda
          request:
            template:
              application/json: "$input.json('$')"
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'aplication/json'"
```

*handler.py*

```
def pdf(event, context):
    pdf = event.get('content')
    out = {'statusCode': 200,
           'isBase64Encoded': False,
           'headers': {"content-type": "application/json"},
           'body': json.dumps({
               'input':  pdf,
               'inputType': 'url',
               #'tags': list(tags.keys()),
               'error': None})}
    return(out)
```

Comment: I also added “multipart/form-data” in "Binary support" via the aws console as described here: https://forum.serverless.com/t/endpoint-for-file-upload-api-gateway-lambda-python/908/2

Comment: I also found out this issue: https://github.com/krisgholson/serverless-thumbnail

Comment: Another answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121011/how-can-i-post-a-pdf-to-aws-lambda/57121631#57121631)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this after a lot of google and with help of the AWS support team.

It turns out that API gateway checks the headers: "Content-Type" or "Accept" in the incoming request and matches it with the settings of *Binary Media Type* to decide which payload is considered as binary. That means we need to specify two content types (multipart/form-data, application/pdf) as *Binary media type*.

It is possible to do this using serveless by using [serverless-apigw-binary](https://github.com/maciejtreder/serverless-apigw-binary) and adding these to *serverless.yaml*:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary 

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:           #list of mime-types
      - 'multipart/form-data'
      - 'application/pdf'
```

But since lambda expects the payload in *application/json* format from the API gateway, the binary data cannot be passed directly. Therefore the settings for ContentHandling should be set to “CONVERT_TO_TEXT”. In the yaml file this translates into:

```
contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_TEXT
```

The final catch was solved by Kris Gohlson at [serverless-thumbnail](https://github.com/krisgholson/serverless-thumbnail). Thank you for that Kris. I just wonder how did you come up with that...

---

*Serverless.yaml*

```
plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary 

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:           #list of mime-types
      - 'multipart/form-data'
      - 'application/pdf'

function:
  pdf:
    handler: handler.pdf
    events:
      - http:
          path: /pdf
          method: post 
          integration: lambda
          request:
            contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_TEXT
            passThrough: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
            template:
              application/pdf: "{'body': $input.json('$')}"
              multipart/form-data: "{'body': $input.json('$')}"
          response:
            contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'aplication/json'"
```