# How can I post a PDF to AWS lambda

Tags: python, post, aws-lambda

I have AWS Lambda set up.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event)
    }
```

I would like to `POST` in a PDF file so that I can operate on it in my lambda function.

Here is my `POST` code

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-API-KEY':'1234',
    'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

files = {
    'document': open('my.pdf', 'rb')
}

r = requests.post(url, files=files,  headers=headers)

display(r)
display(r.text)
```

I am getting the error:

```
<Response [400]>
'{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\\\'-\\\' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
```

How can I `POST` over my PDF and be able to properly send over my PDF and access it in Lambda?

Note:

I am successful if I do this:

```
payload = '{"key1": "val1","key2": 22,"key3": 15,"key4": "val4"}' 
r = requests.post(url = URL, data=payload, headers=HEADERS)
```

It is just the PDF part which I can't get

Comment: Looks like you're in for reading annoying configuration files :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610903/how-to-create-an-aws-lambda-api-gateway-python-function-that-takes-a-pdf-file-as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Took me a ton of time but I think I got it. Essentially it's all about encoding and decoding as bytes. Didn't have to touch the API Gateway at all.

Request:

```
HEADERS = {'X-API-KEY': '12345'}
data = '{"body" : "%s"}' % base64.b64encode(open(path, 'rb').read())
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=HEADERS)
```

In lambda

```
from io import BytesIO
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    pdf64 = event["body"]

    # Need this line as it does 'b'b'pdfdatacontent'.
    pdf64 = pdf64[2:].encode('utf-8')

    buffer = BytesIO()
    content = base64.b64decode(pdf64)
    buffer.write(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked quite well for me:

### Request

```
import requests


file_loc = 'path/to/test.pdf'
data = open(file_loc,'rb').read() #this is a bytes object
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
r.ok #returns True (also a good idea to check r.text

#one-liner
requests.post(url, data=open(file_loc,'rb').read())
```

### Lambda - Python3.8

```
import io, base64

body = event["body"]
attachment = base64.b64decode(body.encode()) #this is a bytes object
buff = io.BytesIO(attachment) #this is now useable - read/write etc.

#one-liner
buff = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(event["body"].encode()))
```

Not quite sure why, but for me base64 encoding (even with urlsafe) in the original request corrupted the file and it was no longer recognised as a PDF in Lambda, so the OP's answer didn't work for me.

Comment: It's been a while since I tried to do this originally, glad you could find another solution. I wasn't happy with Lambda for this project, so I never moved past this question.

Answer (score 0):

### I found the solution by combining certain steps and from this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331009/16330649). Kudos to BrendonParker.

### Step 1

Encode and decode your PDF. There is multiple way to do, but mine is creating endpoint using FastAPI. Within the endpoint, I will create a tempfile for the PDF that will be encode to byte.

```
# create tempfile
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, pdf_file.filename)

# encode
content = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.file.read())
with open(temp_file_path, "wb") as temp_file:
     temp_file.write(content)

# decode
content = base64.b64decode(content)
buffer = io.BytesIO()
buffer.write(content)
```

### Step 2

I am using AWS SAM CLI. Hence, it has given me a `template.yml` file. Within the file, below the `BinaryMediaTypes`, add the following list;

```yaml
BinaryMediaTypes:
  - application/pdf
  - multipart/form-data
```

#### And my PDF now can be used for the next process.