# Uploading PDF to AWS Lambda via API Gateway mangles the bits...why?

Tags: aws-lambda, encoding, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed an AWS Lambda function, written in Python, and AWS API Gateway structure to cause POST requests to an API endpoint to be redirected to my function.  I want to upload a PDF document to my function and have it store the document in a S3 bucket.  The problem I have is that the payload of any POST request to my API is being UTF-8 encoded. I don't want that but can't figure out the magic mojo to disable encoding of the request payload.

I am testing using `curl`, with the following command line:

```
curl -XPOST https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test -H 'content-type: application/pdf' --data-binary @document.pdf
```

UPDATE: I just found the following article describing how API Gateway and Lambda support uploading binary data:

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/handling-binary-data-using-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/

This article suggests that all of the complexities that I discussed in the initial formation of my question (still provided below) should not be necessary.  All I should need to do to upload binary content to my Lambda function is insure that my request includes an appropriate **Content-Type** header. I was already doing that, but I massaged my Curl command a bit (modified above) to define my request in exactly the way that is done in this article.  I still get UTF-8 encoded data and NOT base-64 encoded data.  I tried uploading a jpeg file rather than a PDF so I was doing exactly what was done in the article.  Still no love.  I don't get it.  This article demonstrates exactly what I'm doing.  But I don't get the result it suggests I should.  Ggggrrrr.

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I am using Terraform to define my deployment.  I want to cause the PDF to not be encoded/mangled at all. This is my first time using API Gateway, and I'm obviously missing some bit of config.  The one thing I'm doing specifically right now to say that I want incoming payloads to be treated as binary is via the `binary_media_types` argument to my API definition in Terraform:

```
resource aws_api_gateway_rest_api proxy {

    ...

    binary_media_types = [
        "application/pdf",
        "application/octet-stream",
        "*/*"
    ]
```

This sets the **Binary Media Types** configuration associated with the API I've defined.  I've confirmed via the AWS Console that this setting is having the desired effect...I can see these types in the console.  I should need just the first item in the list, but I've added the others while I try to figure out the problem here.  By adding that wildcard item, I believe that it shouldn't matter what the incoming **Content-Type** is...all payloads should be being treated as binary.

The other bit of config that I know about that might be important is the ***"integration contentHandling property"***.  Here is the key bit of AWS docs that seems to explain all this:

[image: > The combination of your API's binaryMediaTypes, the headers in client requests, and the integration contentHandling property determine how API Gateway encodes payloads.]

I think the case that applies to me here is the one I've highlighted, per what I say above.  This says to me that I shouldn't need to do anything else, per the "unspecified" value in the table for "contentHandling.  I've tried setting the "contentHandling" argument on the integration record of my Terraform config, like this:

```
resource aws_api_gateway_integration proxy {

  ...

  passthrough_behavior    = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
  content_handling        = "CONVERT_TO_BINARY"
}
```

I first tried only specifying the `content_handling` value. I've also tried setting that value to "CONVERT_TO_TEXT", hoping to then get base64-encoded data.  Neither of these has any effect. I've tried adding the `passthrough_behavior` value as shown.  I've also tried replacing "WHEN_NO_MATCH" with "WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES". Nothing I do changes the behavior.  I haven't been able to figure out where these settings would show up in the AWS console.  If I knew they were necessary, I'd explore this further.  But I don't think I need to set these.

What am I missing?  How can I POST a PDF document to my AWS Lambda function through API Gateway and have the payload of the request not be converted in any way? TIA!

NOTE: I am aware of this Q/A: [PDF Uploaded via AWS API Gateway getting corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728961/pdf-uploaded-via-aws-api-gateway-getting-corrupted).  The answer there doesn't apply to me, as I need to avoid having to form-encode the upload.  The client code that will eventually be doing the upload is set in stone and sends a POST request with a payload that is just the bytes of the PDF.

Comment: I am having literally the same exact problem. If you have any advice on how ti fix this I would be hugely appreciative. I'm using the serverless framework instead of terraform for IAC but if you know the root cause of the UTC-8 encoding I can probably adapt it to my serverless.yml file and/or go code.

Comment: I have solved the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76751855/16330649). Hope it can help you!

Answer (score 1):

The process is unfortunately extremely complicated and I have the solution in GoLang but instead of posting it here I made a new question. I didn't want to clutter your question with a bunch of Go code just in case.

[How do you upload and download a binary file to AWS S3 through AWS Lambda and API Gateway in GoLang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525011)

This took me dozens of hours to figure out so I hope it helps you or someone else!

Comment: This is not a valid answer but should be a "close as duplicate" vote or just a regular comment.