# How do you upload and download a binary file to AWS S3 through AWS Lambda and API Gateway in GoLang?

Tags: amazon-web-services, forms, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Using AWS Lambda to serve API calls comes with a lot of caveats and limitations from the proxy integration through AWS API Gateway. One is a payload size limit and another is difficulty with the encoding of payloads either as binary, text, or JSON and in the case of binary - whether it's a binary blob (bytes) or a base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a file to make a round trip through API Gateway -> Lambda -> S3 and back again S3 -> Lambda -> API Gateway you're going to have to configure POSTMAN, API Gateway, Lambda, and your local code correctly to handle base64 encoded payloads. This is one way that API Gateway translates binary blob payloads. There are multiple ways defined [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html) but the following example is the simplest:

**Step 0 - Configuration**

1. You will need to enable binary encoding types for each API gateway that you want to process binary files with.
2. Navigate to AWS Console -> API Gateway -> Select your API -> Settings -> Binary Media Types
3. Add `*/*`
4. Click 'Save Changes'
   OR update your IAC to modify the API Gateway for you. With the Serverless Framework you can do the following:

`serverless.yml`

```
provider:
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - '*/*'
```

**Step 1 - Uploading via POSTMAN**

1. `HTTP PUT` `/staging/api/files/:id/file`
2. `Headers.Content-Type` should be `multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>`
3. `Headers.Content-Length` should be `<calculated when request is sent>`
4. Under Body choose `form-data` and input `filename` under `key` with type `file` and the `value` as a selected binary file to upload. PDFs are a great working example.

**Step 2 - 1 Upload Lambda Handler Function**

```
func UploadLambda(ctx context.Context, lambdaReq events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    if !lambdaReq.IsBase64Encoded {
        return ...
    }

    fileHeaders, err := GetHeaders(lambdaReq, MaxFileSizeBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return ...
    }

    if len(fileHeaders) != 1 {
        return ...
    }

    fileName := uuid.New().String()
    fileExtension := path.Ext(fileHeaders[0].Filename)
    fileName = fileName + fileExtension

    // take the first file uploaded via HTTP and upload it to S3
    uploadResult, err := UploadHeader(fileHeaders[0], os.Getenv("REGION"), os.Getenv("BUCKET"), fileName)
    if err != nil {
         return...
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Status: 200}, nil
}
```

**Step 2 - 2 Parse Headers from Lambda Function**

```
func GetHeaders(lambdaReq events.APIGatewayProxyRequest, maxFileSizeBytes int64) ([]*multipart.FileHeader, error) {
    // https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/issues/117
    headers := http.Header{}

    for header, values := range lambdaReq.Headers {
        headers.Add(header, values)
    }

    contentType := headers.Get("Content-Type")
    if contentType == "" {
        return...
    }

    _, params, err := mime.ParseMediaType(contentType)
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    boundary := params["boundary"]
    if boundary == "" {
        return...
    }


    stringReader := strings.NewReader(lambdaReq.Body) 
    b64Reader := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, stringReader)
    multipartReader := multipart.NewReader(b64Reader, boundary)

    form, err := multipartReader.ReadForm(maxFileSizeBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    var files []*multipart.FileHeader

    for currentFileName := range form.File {
        files = append(files, form.File[currentFileName][0])
    }

    return files, nil
}
```

**Step 2 - 3 Upload to S3 Function**

```
func UploadHeader(fileHeader *multipart.FileHeader, region, bucket, name string) (*UploadRes, error) {

    file, err := fileHeader.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    var fileContents []byte
    _, err = file.Read(fileContents)
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    awsSession, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(region)},
    )
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(awsSession)

    uploadOutput, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(name),
        Body:   file,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    return &UploadRes{
        S3Path: filepath.Join(bucket, name),
        S3URL:  uploadOutput.Location,
    }, nil
}
```

**Step 3 - 1 Download Lambda Handler Function**

```
func DownloadLambda(ctx context.Context, lambdaReq events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    file := Get(...)

    fileBytes, err := Download(os.Getenv("REGION"), os.Getenv("BUCKET"), file.Name)
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    return FileB64Res(file.ContentType, nil, fileBytes)
}
```

**Step 3 - 2 Download S3 Function**

```
func Download(region, bucket, name string) ([]byte, error) {
    awsSession, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(region)},
    )
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(awsSession)

    var fileBytes []byte
    writeAtBuffer := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer(fileBytes)

    getObjectInput := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(name),
    }

    // functional options pattern
    bytesDownloaded, err := downloader.Download(writeAtBuffer, getObjectInput, func(downloader *s3manager.Downloader) {
        downloader.Concurrency = 0
    })
    if err != nil {
        return...
    }

    if bytesDownloaded == 0 {
        return...
    }

    return writeAtBuffer.Bytes(), nil
}


func FileB64Res(contentType string, headers map[string]string, fileBytes []byte) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    if headers == nil {
        headers = map[string]string{
            ContentTypeKey: contentType,
        }
    } else {
        headers[ContentTypeKey] = contentType
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode:      http.StatusOK,
        Headers:         headers,
        Body:            base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(fileBytes),
        IsBase64Encoded: true,
    }, nil
}
```

**Step 4 - 1 Download via POSTMAN**

1. `HTTP GET` `/staging/api/files/:id/file`
2. Set `Headers.Accept` to `*/*`
3. You will know everything is working correctly when the 'preview' of the Body in POSTMAN renders a PDF or image. If you get no preview - the bytes are still getting mangled when translating from bytes (postman) -> b64 string (api gateway) -> bytes (S3 storage) -> b64 string (API Gateway) -> bytes (postman)

This is absolutely everything you should need to handle binary payloads in GoLang for AWS Lambda with API Gateway as a proxy. Don't forget CORS when moving away from POSTMAN to a browser!

Comment: Worth noting that this does not work for anything over 6MB since that is the hard limit for request and response payload size. You should do this with S3 presigned urls instead of routing it through a lambda manually.

Comment: A very good point. However I think the current limit is 10MB. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Pre-signed URLs might've been a stronger starting point however I wanted to do the most legwork possible on the API side for an easy client side integration so native uploading seemed the easiest.

Comment: For the API gateway, yes. But the lambda itself has an even lower limit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html .

Comment: i honestly had no idea - thank you for sharing that